# What I can do with this error? ValueError: Expected singleton: sale.order.line(26, 27)

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I am modifying a button (Confirm sale) in the sale.order.form so that when I press , I immediately take the inventory (stock.picking.form). This works perfectly . but when I want to validate the function for when a product is stockable type . It works only when I select only one product in the order .

The problem is when I select more than one product , as in the following image:

[image]

This is the function of the 'Confirm sale' button.

```
@api.multi
def action_confirm(self):
    for order in self:
        order.state = 'sale'
        if self.env.context.get('send_email'):
            self.force_quotation_send()
        order.order_line._action_procurement_create()
        if not order.project_id:
            for line in order.order_line:
                if line.product_id.invoice_policy == 'cost':
                    order._create_analytic_account()
                    break
    if self.env['ir.values'].get_default('sale.config.settings', 'auto_done_setting'):
        self.action_done()
```

****HERE BEGINS THE CHANGING FUNCTION****************

```
if self.order_line.product_id.product_tmpl_id.type in 'product':        

    action = self.env.ref('stock.action_picking_tree_all')

    result = {
        'name': action.name,
        'help': action.help,
        'type': action.type,
        'view_type': action.view_type,
        'view_mode': action.view_mode,
        'target': action.target,
        'context': action.context,
        'res_model': action.res_model,
    }

    pick_ids = sum([order.picking_ids.ids for order in self], [])

    if len(pick_ids) > 1:
        result['domain'] = "[('id','in',["+','.join(map(str, pick_ids))+"])]"
    elif len(pick_ids) == 1:
        form = self.env.ref('stock.view_picking_form', False)
        form_id = form.id if form else False
        result['views'] = [(form_id, 'form')]
        result['res_id'] = pick_ids[0]
    return result
```

If someone could help me with this problem. How it could validate that the system can accept more than one product in the order? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Why are you using `sum( )`?

Comment: It is a function that was extracted on the other hand , it comes by default so .
The only thing I did was to include it in if loop.

**if self.order_line.product_id.product_tmpl_id.type in 'product':**

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you are using self as a singleton, and as the method has the @api.multi decorator, it could be a list. I think that, if your modification is under the first for loop, it could work if you change your code to:

```
...
if order.order_line.product_id.product_tmpl_id.type in 'product':    
...
```

Edit:

The exception could also be raise when you access self.order_line in the same line. You're doing as if it were a single element and it also could be a list. You should iterate over the self.order_line list:

```
...
for line in self.order_line:
  if line.product_id.product_tmpl_id.type in 'product':  
...
```